# Imput console commands through a desktop app get returned rows back?

Tags: c#

I am trying to input console commands on a desktop app (through a text box) click a button, execute the command and get the returned  values back for display.

The point is, I want to make my work faster and less stressful when trying to input repetitive commands on the console over and over again everyday.

I know some console application programming on C# and web applications(.NET, ADO.NET) on C# as well, but nothing about desktop applications. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The [Process class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) can be used to start an application, and read it's output (from the standard output or standard error streams).

For example, to start a process, and read it's "output", you could use:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = "Foo.exe";
p.Start();

// Read the output
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make a basic windows forms applications, you could store repetitive commands in a local file and have a mechanism to choose a command from this file in your application and run it. Windows forms shouldn't be too hard for you. it is just drag and drop.